# Create a circle with a radius & projection - Open Layers

Tags: vector, geometry, openlayers

Currently whenever I zoom in / out my circle looses the area or the radius will be incorrect, I guess my radius need to have a projected to the map. Here is my code

```
 ...
 var circle = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: radius, //I guess this is wrong
            fill: null,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.9)',
                width: 2
            })
        })
    })
});

map.addLayer(circle);

var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([x, y]));
circle.getSource().addFeature(marker);
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of a Circle style in in pixels, it does not change with the view resolution.  For a radius in projection units you need a Circle geometry

```
style: new ol.style.Style({
            geometry: function (feature) {
                return new ol.geom.Circle(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), radius);
            },
            fill: null,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.9)',
                width: 2
            })
    })
```

Note that a projection unit circle is not geodesic, so it may not be a true radius or a true circle on the ground - see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-geodesic.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>WFS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.3.0/ol.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.3.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
  <style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script>

const radius = 500000;

const feature1 = new ol.Feature(
  new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-45, 0]))
);
feature1.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({
    geometry: function (feature) {
      return new ol.geom.Circle(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), radius);
    },
    fill: null,
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.9)',
      width: 2
    })
  })
);

const feature2 = new ol.Feature(
  new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([45, 0]))
);
feature2.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({
    geometry: function (feature) {
      return ol.geom.Polygon.circular(
        ol.proj.toLonLat(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()),
        radius
      ).transform('EPSG:4326', map.getView().getProjection());
    },
    fill: null,
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.9)',
      width: 2
    })
  })
);

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [feature1, feature2]
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});

let latitude = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  latitude += 0.1;
  latitude %= 60;
  feature1.getGeometry().setCoordinates(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-45, latitude]))
  feature2.getGeometry().setCoordinates(ol.proj.fromLonLat([45, latitude]))
}, 10);

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but the circle is not drawing this time and there are is no error displayed

Comment: I have added a working example (and a geodesic circle for comparison) to the answer.

Comment: Mike, why is the radius disappearing at certain zoom level. Thanks anyway